# Vuetify 3 beta gives "Error: Could not find injected Vuetify layout"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, material-ui

I am using the Vuetify 3 beta with vue-cli v5, but when I try to use `v-app-bar` in my template, I get `Error: Could not find injected Vuetify layout`

Comment: There's not enough context to determine the problem. Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Answer (score 25):

This just happened to me. The cause was that I had the `v-app-bar` outside of the `v-app`. Moving it inside fixed it.

Comment: what about when testing the component `v-app-bar`? In this case, I don't want to wrap my component in `v-app`

Comment: This collides with the recommendation for Nuxt3 scaffolding, that puts the v-app component inside the NuxtLayout component. See https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#using-nuxt-3. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 17):

This error occurs when you forget to wrap your vuetify code inside the `v-app` tag. To fix that add the `v-app` tag as shown in the code below:

```html
<v-app>

  <!-- Your appBar goes here -->
  <v-app-bar  title="My site" app>
  </v-app-bar>  

</v-app>
```

Comment: what about when testing the component `v-app-bar`? In this case, I don't want to wrap my component in `v-app`.

Comment: Then, wrap your app.vue content for every component to be wrapped by default.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where my component `AppFooter.vue` looked like this

```
<template lang="pug">
v-footer(app)
</template>
```

and my simple mounting test had `Error: [Vuetify] Could not find injected layout`. I resolved the issue by adding [v-layout](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-layout/).

```
<template lang="pug">
v-layout
  v-footer(app)
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `<v-layout>` like this:

```
<template>
    <v-layout>
        <v-footer>
        </v-footer>
    </v-layout>
</template>`
```