# Combination of Vue 3 + Vuetify 3 + vue/test-utils, results in "Could not find injected Vuetify layout" error

Tags: components, vuetify.js, vuejs3, vue-test-utils

Does anyone know how to do component testing in `@vue/test-utils v2` library, while using `Vuetify 3 Beta` version? I am also using `Vue3 composition API` to define my components. The documentation that i found here https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/unit-testing/#spec-tests is not working, since it is for `Vuetify v2` and `@vue/test-utils v1`

This is my plugins/vuetify.js

```
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css';
import 'vuetify/styles';
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify';

export default createVuetify();
```

This is my code in NavBar.spec.js

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import NavBar from '../NavBar.vue';
import Vuetify from '../../plugins/vuetify';

describe('NavBar', () => {
    it('No properties [correct]', () => {
        mount(NavBar, {
            props: {},
            global: {
                plugins: [Vuetify]
            }
        });
        // check if navbar renders
        cy.get('.main')
            .first();

    });
});
```

This is the error i receive:
`Could not find injected Vuetify layout`

Comment: I'm stuck with the same problem, did you find a solution yet? Both answers don't work for me.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue and I am using vitest.

Thanks for this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/14749)

I solved it by adding `global.plugin` in each test file as below.

### ToDoList.test.js

```js
import { createVuetify } from "vuetify";
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import ToDoList from "./ToDoList.vue";

describe("ToDoList.vue", () => {
    const vuetify = createVuetify()

    it("renders", () => {
        const wrapper = mount(ToDoList, {
            props: {
                title: "testTitle",
                text: "testText",
            },
            global: {
                plugins: [vuetify],
            },
        });
    });
});
```

I also need to add some configuration in `vite.config.js` as below

### vite.config.js

```js
/// <reference types="vitest" />

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import vuetify from "vite-plugin-vuetify";

const path = require("path");

export default defineConfig({
    //...other config...
    test: {
        globals: true,
        environment: "jsdom",
        setupFiles: "vuetify.config.js",
        deps: {
            inline: ["vuetify"],
        },
    },
});
```

Finally, I create a `vuetify.config.js` file in the root directory referenced from the setupFiles properties of `vite.config.js`

### vuetify.config.js

```js
global.CSS = { supports: () => false };
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot. I also found two repositories that can be helpful as templates: https://github.com/peshanghiwa/Vue3-Vite-Vuetify3-Typescript-Template and https://github.com/logue/vite-vuetify-ts-starter

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue, someone answered [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71653726/vuetify-3-beta-gives-error-could-not-find-injected-vuetify-layout) saying they fixed the error by moving their component within the `<v-app>` tag.

If like me however your component was already within your top level `<v-app>` tag, other people [online](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vuetify-data-app-true-and-problems-rendering-v-dialog-in-unit-tests/27495/2) had success by adding

```js
let el = document.createElement("div");
el.setAttribute("data-app", "true");
document.body.appendChild(el);
```

before your test, but this also didn't work for my setup.

*(I found wrapping my component in a `<v-app>` tag got my tests to work, but you shouldn't have multiple of those on your page and you don't want to have to add extra code to every component just for your tests to pass.)*

If that solution doesn't work for you either though, I eventually worked around it by mounting the `VApp` component itself and passing my component to it as the default slot content, like so:

```js
import { h } from "vue";
import { VApp } from "vuetify/components";
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent.vue";

describe("Test", () => {
  it("should", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(VApp, {
      slots: {
        default: h(MyComponent),
      }
    })
  )}
)}
```

(thanks to [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/41#issuecomment-327179174) for the assist)

Hopefully this is just an issue as Vuetify 3 is still in beta, and once they formalise best testing practice we should be able to remove this custom fix.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is a very specific problem. I managed to get it working by creating a VuetifyWrapper component that has the <v-app> as top element and it loads a component dynamically with <component :is... />. So it's something similar to what you did with the slot.

Comment: I had the same issue, but when I try to wrap it inside the `VApp`, I get the error "Cannot find module 'vuetify/lib/components' from 'tests/unit/example.spec.ts'". Do you have extra configuration in your setup or babel files?

Comment: @MarcoArruda, please see my answer. hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

I post my minimal configuration that worked for me at the time of writing for the combination
**Vue 3, Vite 4, Vuetify 3, Typescript 4**.

It's based on the answers from this page and from other sources I had to investigate to make it work.
The code is based on the default template built with the Vue bootstrap tool, so it has a separate `vitest.config.ts` which extends the main `vite.config` which doesn't need changes.

The `ResizeObserverStub` is needed to resolve `ReferenceError: ResizeObserver is not defined` mentioned here: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/14749#issuecomment-1481141623.

According to the suggestions from that Github issue, the `vite-plugin-vuetify` is not needed, so the solution works without it.

**package.json (excerpt)**

```
"dependencies": {
  "vue": "^3.2.47",
  "vuetify": "^3.1.10"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@vue/test-utils": "^2.3.0",
  "vite": "^4.1.4",
  "vitest": "^0.29.1",
}
```

**vitest.config.ts**

```
/// <reference types="vitest" />

import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url'
import { mergeConfig } from 'vite'
import { configDefaults, defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'

import viteConfig from './vite.config'

export default mergeConfig(
  viteConfig,
  defineConfig({
    test: {
      environment: 'jsdom',
      exclude: [...configDefaults.exclude, 'e2e/*'],
      root: fileURLToPath(new URL('./', import.meta.url)),
      deps: {
        inline: ["vuetify"]
      },
      setupFiles: ['./vitest/setup.ts']
    }
  })
)
```

**vitest/setup.ts**

```
// Fix undefined ResizeObserver error
class ResizeObserverStub {
  observe () { }
  unobserve () { }
  disconnect () { }
}

window.ResizeObserver = window.ResizeObserver || ResizeObserverStub;
```

**HomeView.spec.ts**

```
import { describe, test } from 'vitest'
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'

import { createVuetify } from "vuetify"
import * as components from "vuetify/components"
import * as directives from "vuetify/directives"

import HomeView from '@/views/HomeView.vue'


const vuetify = createVuetify({ components, directives })

describe('HomeView', () => {
  test('init', async () => {
    const view = mount(HomeView, { global: {plugins: [vuetify]} })
    console.log(view.html())  // check the Vuetify components are rendered to HTML correctly
    // ... test code
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the minimalist answer using an example straight of the scaffolding tool.

What fixed it for me was the deps: {  inline: ["vuetify"]  }, before that I encountered issues looking like Unknown file extension ".css"

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue in Vuetify 3 + `@testing-library/vue` (should also work with `@vue/test-utils` and `mount`):

```
import { VuetifyLayoutKey } from "vuetify/lib/composables/layout.mjs"

//..

global: {
  // fix: [Vuetify] Could not find injected layout
  provide: {
    [VuetifyLayoutKey]: {
       mainStyles: { value: "" },
       register: () => ({
         layoutItemStyles: { value: { top: 0 } },
       }),
       unregister: () => ({}),
     },
  },
}
```

Full render function:

```
// test-utils.js

import { render } from "@testing-library/vue"
import { createVuetify } from "vuetify"
import * as components from "vuetify/components"
import * as directives from "vuetify/directives"
import { VuetifyLayoutKey } from "vuetify/lib/composables/layout.mjs"

const vuetify = createVuetify({
  components,
  directives,
})

const customRender: typeof render = (ui, options?) => {
  // should also work with `mount` and `shallowMount` instead of `render`
  return render(ui, {
    global: {
      ...options?.global,
      plugins: [vuetify, ...(options?.global?.plugins ?? [])],
      // fix: [Vuetify] Could not find injected layout
      provide: {
        [VuetifyLayoutKey]: {
          mainStyles: { value: "" },
          register: () => ({
            layoutItemStyles: { value: { top: 0 } },
          }),
          unregister: () => ({}),
        },
        ...options?.global?.provide,
      },
    ...options,
  })
}

// re-export everything
export * from "@testing-library/vue"
export { default as userEvent } from "@testing-library/user-event"
export { axe } from "vitest-axe"
// override render method
export { customRender as render }
```

The error only happens in components that use `useLayout` from Vuetify composables. In my case I had a `v-main` and `v-navigation-drawer` component. Other components might require more mocks.